# PHP: get_object_vars for uninitialized typed fields to get field names

Tags: php

I am starting a PHP project, although I am usually a java dev. I found out that **PHP 7.4** finally allows [typed properties](https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74). So I created a class like so:

```
class SenderPdo
{
    /* Metadata */

    /** phpdoc */
    public int $id;
}
```

Now, I wanted to get all the available field names. Usually I’d do this using  `get_object_vars(new SenderPdo())` and wrap that into a call to `array_keys()`. However, as `get_object_vars` will also fetch the values, I get an (expected and documented) Exception that not all of my fields are initialised.

Now, is there a way to get all the field names via some kind of reflection? I was not able to find a method similar to `get_object_vars` which does not read the fields.

The alternative would be to [initialise all the properties](https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Comment: `get_class_vars('SenderPdo')`

Comment: get_class_vars will actually get the contents.